# How to set nested route path same level as the parent route?

Tags: ember.js

```
  this.route('browse', { path: '/points' }, function() {
    this.route('quiz', { path: '/quiz' });
    this.route('learn', { path: '/learn' });
  });
  this.route('post', { path: '/post' }, function() {
    this.route('star', { path: '/star' });
    this.route('marked', { path: '/marked' });
  });
```

The reason I want to do this is that I would like to share same base template between nested routes and I do not put all these into application template (otherwise I need to place so many condition block in it).

What I want to achive is

```
browse       -> /points
browse.quiz  -> /quiz
browse.learn -> /learn

post         -> /posts
post.star    -> /star
post.marked  -> /marked
```

Comment: there is `templateName` property in route. In `browse.quiz` route.js , you can say `templateName: 'browse'`. if this is not what what you want, then you might be interested in `this.route('quiz', { resetNamespace: true })` Again `resetNamespace` is not good approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [resetNamespace](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/d3ceb22/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/router.js#L1168)

```
this.route('browse', { path: '/points' }, function() {
    this.route('quiz', { resetNamespace: true });
    this.route('learn', { resetNamespace: true });
  });
```

Comment: Assertion Failed: You attempted to define a `{{link-to "browse.quiz"}}` but did not pass the parameters required for generating its dynamic segments. There is no route named browse.quiz

Comment: Just try `quiz` alone

Comment: Remove the `browse` does solve the issue, however the url is the still the same. It just change the way how I refer to a route. From `browse.starred` to `starred`.

Comment: I think I have no choice but to bear with the ugly URL ;(